# Finding out the maximum pixel size of characters in a limited area

Tags: c#, string, split, pixel

I'm trying to implement a feature that shows the biggest possible character pixel count that fits into the area.

**Example 1**:
Imagine an LED display with size: 100x20 px. A string that needs to be shown is: **volutpa commodo diam**

After doing everything by hand, I was able to determine that the biggest possible pixel size of the characters without splitting/dividing words is 8x8 px. Each character must have the same pixel size.

The string above will be successfully shown on the LED display if the character pixel size is 8x8 px. Expected output: **8**

**Example 2**:
Imagine an LED display with size: 100x20 px. A string that needs to be shown is: **dio volutpa diam**

The string above will be successfully shown on the LED display if the character pixel size is 9x9 px. Expected output: **9**

**Example 3**:
Imagine an LED display with size: 55x25 px. A string that needs to be shown is: **dio tuo diam**

The string above will be successfully shown on the LED display if the character pixel size is 8x8 px. Expected output: **8**

**Example 4**:
Imagine an LED display with size: 20x6 px. A string that needs to be shown is: **tuo volutpa**

The string above will be successfully shown on the LED display if the character pixel size is 2x2 px. Expected output: **2**

Note: Every character in a string (including space) must be the same pixel size (e.g. 6x6 px) to fill the whole area (LED display) and the words in the string must not be split/divided.

In this [**example 1**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdXWV.png) you can see the "hand made" image of what I'm trying to achieve. The whole layout represents the area size (100x20 px) while the black boxes represent the biggest possible character pixel size (8x8 px). If I use (9x9 px or more) for the character size the text wouldn't fit and if I use (7x7 px or less) there would be too much empty space.

In this [**example 2**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OqLd.png) you can see the "hand made" image of what I'm trying to achieve. The whole layout represents the area size (100x20 px) while the black boxes represent the biggest possible character pixel size (9x9 px). If I use (10x10 px or more) for the character size the text wouldn't fit and if I use (8x8 px or less) there would be too much empty space. We should ignore the space at the end of the word if the line is about to end.

**Expected**:

Line 1: dio_volutpa

Line 2: diam

**Actual**:

Line 1: dio_volutpa_

Line 2: diam

In this [**example 3**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQtDl.png) you can see the "hand made" image of what I'm trying to achieve. The whole layout represents the area size (55x25 px) while the black boxes represent the biggest possible character pixel size (8x8 px). If I use (9x9 px or more) for the character size the text wouldn't fit and if I use (7x7 px or less) there would be too much empty space. Red boxes are there to show you that there is no space for the next word, therefore it needs to go to a new line OR decrease it's pixel size if there is no line space below.

What would be the best way to implement this in C#?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String sentence = "volutpa commodo diam";
        int width = 100; // 100 px
        int height = 20; // 20 px
        int pixelSize = height / 2; // Starting pixel size (10)
        int maxLines = height / pixelSize; // Max. available lines in the area
        int currentLine = 1; // Starting line

        string[] words = sentence.Split(' '); // Splitting words from the sentence. words[1] = volutpa, words[2] = commodo, words[3] = diam

        // Length of the words
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Word " + i + " length: " + words[i].Length * pixelSize);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I've made this for now, but can't figure it out how to continue. I would appreciate some tips and ideas.

Comment: Is there a line limit?

Comment: No, the only limit is the area that needs to fit the text with the largest possible pixel size for the characters.
If there is no space for the next word, it needs to go to a new line OR decrease it's pixel size if there is no line space below.

Here is a new example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQtDl.png

Comment: Above example: The available LED display area is 55x25 px. We need to find the largest possible pixel size for the characters to fit the text: dio tuo diam
We can see that the words need to go to a new line as there is no available pixel space next to them. We could lower the pixel size, but that would lead to too much empty screen space, that's why we are looking for the biggest possible pixel to fill the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my final solution based on your updated question.
please read comments inside the code.

**UPDATE**
inside `fixtoFitMatrix()` method space will be take in consideration only between 2 words.

**UPDATE 2** 

please read comment 1, comment 2 and comment 3 inside the code.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication29
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Check("volutpa commodo diam", 100, 20);
            Check("dio volutpa diam", 100, 20);
            Check("dio tuo diam", 55, 25);
            Check("tuo volutpa", 20, 6);
            Check("volutpa", 23, 2);
            Check("diam tu diam op comodo", 10, 20);
            Check("volutpas di diam e commodo", 65, 65);
            Check("diamo volutpasoni onedo commodoso", 10, 40);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void Check(string txt,int w,int h)
        {
            String sentence = txt;
            int width = w;
            int height = h;

            string[] words = sentence.Split(' '); 

            int maxLines;
            int pixelSize = GetPixelSize(words, height, width,out maxLines);

            Console.WriteLine(sentence);
            // length of the words
            for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {               
                Console.WriteLine("Word " + i + " length: " + words[i].Length * pixelSize );
            }

            Console.WriteLine("pixel size will be " + pixelSize + " lines: " + maxLines );
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------");
        }

        private static int GetPixelSize(string[] words, int height, int width,out int maxlines)
        {
            int lines = 1;
            int basepx = GetBasePixelSize(words, height, width,1,ref lines);

            // fix if not each line is fitted to width or the height of the matrix
            int finalpx = fixtoFitMatrix(basepx,words,width,height,lines);
            maxlines = lines;
            return finalpx;
        }

        private static int fixtoFitMatrix(int basepx, string[] words,int width,int height,int lines)
        {
            List<LedLine> ldlines = new List<LedLine>();
            int currentline = 0;
            // set text for each line
            LedLine l = new LedLine() { LineNumber = currentline, LineText = words[0]};
            ldlines.Add(l);
            for (int i = 1;i< words.Length;i++)
            {
                var currentstring = words[i];

                if (ldlines[currentline].Len * basepx + basepx + currentstring.Length * basepx <= width)
                {
                    // add to current line
                    ldlines[currentline].LineText = ldlines[currentline].LineText + currentstring;
                }
                else
                {
                    // it is a new line
                    currentline++;
                    LedLine newl = new LedLine() { LineNumber = currentline, LineText = currentstring };
                    ldlines.Add(newl);
                }
            }
            // px size is also a function of the width
            // for example:
            // on surface of 100X20 volutpa commodo diam will be 8px and dio volutpa diam will be 9px
            // that happens because commodo diam is the length of 12 and 12*9=108 and the width is only 100 so we will need to fix
            //fix will be chcked if the number of lines requeired is not the same in ldlines.count that means that we will need to "shrink" px by 1 every recursive call
            if (ldlines.Count > lines)
            {
                return fixtoFitMatrix(basepx - 1, words, width,height, lines);
            }
            // comment 1: we need to check the height also
            else if (lines * basepx > height)
            {
                return fixtoFitMatrix(basepx - 1, words, width, height, lines);
            }
            return basepx;
        }

        private static int GetBasePixelSize(string[] words, int height,int width,int linesneeded,ref int finalnumberoflines,int specialH = 0)
        {
            int h = (int)Math.Ceiling(((double)height / (double)linesneeded));
            if (specialH > 0)
                h = specialH;

            var lines = linesneeded;
            var accumulate = 0;

            for (int i = 0;i< words.Length;i++)
            {
                accumulate += words[i].Length * h;
                // add space if it is not the last word
                if (i < words.Length - 1)
                {
                    accumulate += h;
                }

                // more line needed - call recursivaly until we get the number of lines needed
                if (accumulate / lines > width)
                {
                    return GetBasePixelSize(words, height, width, linesneeded+1,ref finalnumberoflines,specialH);
                }
            }
            finalnumberoflines = lines;


            // comment 2 - special case - if there is a single word that is larger than all px (int h) we will decrease h, for example on matrix of 10*20 the word 'comodo'
            // can be displayed only when h=1 because if its 2 then 2* 6 = 12
            // we will strat all over again with the new size
            if (words.Any(x => x.Length * h > width))
            {
                string specialword = words.Where(x => x.Length * h > width).FirstOrDefault();
                // decrease h by the equation X = height/word.length, if the result is under 1 its not possible to do that
                h = (int)Math.Floor((double)width/ (double)specialword.Length);
                // comment 3 - if h = 0 exit the method and return 0 - it is not possible with the given conditions 
                // (for example matrix of 10X40 with the sentence 'diamo volutpasoni onedo commodoso' is not possible)
                if (h == 0)
                    return 0;

                finalnumberoflines = 1;
                return GetBasePixelSize(words, height, width, 1, ref finalnumberoflines,h);
            }

            return h;
        }
    }

    public class LedLine
    {
        public int LineNumber { get; set; }
        public string LineText { get; set; }
        public int Len
        {
            get
            {
                return LineText.Length;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

> volutpa commodo diam
>  Word 0 length: 56
>  Word 1 length:
>   56
>  Word 2 length: 32
>  pixel size will be 8 lines: 2
>   --------------------------------------------
>  dio volutpa diam
>  Word 0 length: 27
>  Word 1 length: 63
>  Word 2 length:
>   36
>  pixel size will be 9 lines: 2
>   --------------------------------------------
>  dio tuo diam
>  Word 0 length: 24
>  Word 1 length: 24
>  Word 2 length: 32
>   pixel size will be 8 lines: 3
>   --------------------------------------------
>  tuo volutpa
>  Word 0 length: 6
>  Word 1 length: 14
>  pixel size will be 2
>   lines: 2
>   --------------------------------------------
>  volutpa
>  Word 0 length: 14
>  pixel size will be 2 lines: 1
>   --------------------------------------------
>  diam tu diam op comodo
>  Word 0 length: 4
>  Word 1 length: 2
>  Word 2 length:
>   4
>  Word 3 length: 2
>  Word 4 length: 6
>  pixel size will be
>   1 lines: 3
>   --------------------------------------------
>  volutpas di diam e commodo
>  Word 0 length: 64
>  Word 1 length: 16
>  Word 2
>   length: 32
>  Word 3 length: 8
>  Word 4 length: 56
>  pixel
>   size will be 8 lines: 4
>   --------------------------------------------
>  diamo volutpasoni onedo commodoso
>  Word 0 length: 0
>  Word 1 length: 0
>  Word
>   2 length: 0
>  Word 3 length: 0
>  pixel size will be 0 lines:
>   7
>   --------------------------------------------

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, this is not what I meant.
I should have added this example. Imagine an LED display with 100x20 pixels that need to display a certain sentence (e.g. volutpa commodo diam) while using the biggest possible pixel size for each character (8x8 px) without splitting the words. The area (LED display) must be filled as much as possible, meaning that the words can be in multiple lines, like it's shown on the attached image.
I will update the original post.

Comment: OK. now I understand the question much better. when I will be near my pc I will update my answer, if somebody else will not answer this question until then.

Comment: @rob1982 please see my new answer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the code but the output seems to be incorrect as the final number should be 8 px. Instead of that it shows 10 px which means that the whole sentence (included spaces) won't fit in the area (LED display). I have edited my original post and included more examples with the expected outputs.

Comment: Thank you for the new revision. It looks VERY promising.
The only thing left is to ignore the space at the end of the word if the line is about to end.

Example:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OqLd.png
Display dimensions: 100x20px
String: dio volutpa diam
Problem is that the space after the word "volutpa" is causing the pixel size to shrink.

Expected output: 9
Actual output: 8

Expected:
Line 1: dio_volutpa
Line 2: diam

Actual:
Line 1: dio_volutpa_
Line 2: diam

Comment: @rob1982, OK now I understand why dio volutpa diam gave me 8 and not 9, I have fixed it, now in fixByWidthAndNumofLines() method, space is checked (basepx) only if there is a word before the next word -if (ldlines[currentline].Len * basepx + basepx + currentstring.Length * basepx <= width). lines will be arranged according to the image. first line= dio(27) + space(9) +volutpa(63) = 99. second line = diam(36)

Comment: Thanks! While it works flawlessly for the strings above, I noticed that it doesn't work for some.
Example 1: Display with dimensions 23x2 px should display the word: volutpa
Expected result is 2 while the actual result is 1.
Example 2: Display with dimensions 10x20 px should display the sentence: diam tu diam op comodo
Expected result is 1 while the actual result is 2.

Comment: Example 3: Display with dimensions 65x65 px should display the sentence: volutpas di diam e commodo
Expected result is 8 while the actual result is 12
Example 4: Display with dimensions 10x40 px should display the sentence: diamo volutpasoni onedo commodoso 
Expected result is 0 as some words are too long to display, while the actual result is 3.

I really appreciate your help. I've been dealing with this for days and it works great on paper, but I can't figure it out how do it in C#.

Comment: @rob1982, please see update 2 and read comment 1, comment 2 and comment 3 inside the code.

Comment: Thank you! It works great. Also very informative comments. I would upvote your answers but I'm lacking reputation.

Comment: Glad I could help (-:  I made some minor fixes just now and removed some comments. now it is really the final version.

Comment: Just one more thing. I noticed that I'm getting the wrong output with these dimensions: 420x100 pixels and using string: aaa bbbb ccc dddddd aaa bbbb dddddd aaa eeeee    The result should be 26 but the actual result I'm getting is 25. Here is the example: **[link](https://imgur.com/a/qxO7gT6)** On this image it is shown that the string can be shown using only 3 lines with the pixel size of 26px instead of using 4 lines with the pixel size of 25px with empty bottom line.